# Show TipTip on Document Ready

Tags: jquery, tiptip

I am using Drew Wilsons Tip Tip Plugin with the modified methods to "show", "hide" or "destroy" a TipTip...

For some reason I cannot get all the tooltips to show on document ready, but they wont come up I wonder if someone can lead me in the right direction... here is my code....

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".botpage a").tipTip({ content: "This is an anchor tag!"});
$(".botpage a").tipTip('show');
});
```

TipTip Defaults

```
var defaults = {
        activation: "hover", // How to show (and hide) the tooltip. Can be: hover, focus, click and manual.
        keepAlive: false, // When true the tooltip won't disapper when the mouse moves away from the element. Instead it will be hidden when it leaves the tooltip.
        maxWidth: "200px", // The max-width to set on the tooltip. You may also use the option cssClass to set this.
        edgeOffset: 6, // The offset between the tooltip arrow edge and the element that has the tooltip.
        defaultPosition: "bottom", // The position of the tooltip. Can be: top, right, bottom and left.
        delay: 400, // The delay in msec to show a tooltip.
        fadeIn: 200, // The length in msec of the fade in.
        fadeOut: 200, // The length in msec of the fade out.
        attribute: "title", // The attribute to fetch the tooltip text if the option content is false.
        content: false, // HTML or String or Function (that returns HTML or String) to fill TipTIp with
        enter: function () { }, // Callback function before a tooltip is shown.
        afterEnter: function () { }, // Callback function after a tooltip is shown.
        exit: function () { }, // Callback function before a tooltip is hidden.
        afterExit: function () { }, // Callback function after a tooltip is hidden.
        cssClass: '' // CSS class that will be applied on the tooltip before showing only for this instance of tooltip.
    };
```

HTML

```
<div class="botpage">
<a>TOOLTIP YAY!</a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong??? if you need any other code let me know!

Comment: "with the modified methods to "show", "hide" or "destroy" a TipTip" And did you modify the methods to do this?

Comment: I thought Drew wilsons new version already had these modifications... check out this page: http://drew.tenderapp.com/discussions/tiptip/70-updated-tiptip-with-new-features

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ygswQ/

Comment: Weird I dont know why mine isnt working, here is my URL: check it out http://www.convurgency.com/tools/googlebot.php just enter a URL and hover over the anchor tags to see the tooltips

Comment: Oh and Im using jquery 1.5.2 min...

Comment: Ah ha. I see the issue. It *is* showing a tooltip. But it's only showing ONE. It looks like the plugin might only let you show one at a time? See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ygswQ/1/. So, you may need to modify the source code or use a different tool tip plugin that lets you do this.

Comment: Ahhhhh I get it, damn that sucks, I need to show them all... do you know of any tooltip that will let this happen? Thanks for all of your help by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha. I see the issue. It is showing a tooltip. But it's only showing ONE. It looks like the plugin might only let you show one at a time. See this updated fiddle: jsfiddle.net/ygswQ/1. So, you may need to modify the source code or use a different tool tip plugin that lets you do this.

There's a *bunch* of jQuery tooltip plugins. One of the more popular ones I believe is qtip. Here is an example of how you can do it in qTip: http://jsfiddle.net/GEycz/